# C# - Errors trying to Save Image from program to desktop in tool

Tags: c#, vb.net

So my tool gets a picture online and puts it in the middle, i just wonder how do i save?

here is my code i used but it has error's i wonder why?

```
if Me.picturebox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.Picturebox1.Image.Save(IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.filesystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, textBox6.Text));
```

Here is a Gyazo image of it. The program works properly i just want to get it to save the Image.

https://gyazo.com/913191e35c3caab9016cd09b7fd28b59

---

If you really need My code before this when it grabs the picture here it is

```
 pictureBox1.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new System.IO.MemoryStream(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData("http://api.skype.com/users/" + textBox6.Text + "/profile/avatar")));
```

Comment: What are the errors?  What is your question?

Comment: if you are getting the Image then you should be able to save the image to your local

Comment: You are mixing C# and VB.NET code

Comment: The errors are "me" "isnot" "then" "Path" "My"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C# version:

```
if (picturebox1.Image != null)
{
    picturebox1.Image.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.Desktop), textBox6.Text));
}
```

Comment: Thanks it fixed it a bit but now picturebox1 does not exist in the current context. It looks like https://gyazo.com/595b2899ee6d8180808f90e0d6792b9f

Comment: @AaronMC What did you call your picture box control?

Comment: My picturebox i entred the URL as "http://api.skype.com/users/pyromcee/profile/avatar" under "Image Location" The code when i double click is nothing. I used the top code with the Save button when i double click.

Comment: heres my Skype tool download - http://www.gcpmc.org/uploads/4/8/3/4/48346419/zippymodss_skype_tool_2.0.zip  if you want you can open it and go to "grabbers" tab and enter a skype username and hit "grab" it pulls the image up properly and works, i just want to know how to get the button that says "save" to to save the photo without error.

Comment: I fixed the "path error" by adding "System.IO.Path" instead of "IO.Path" all i got is Error #1 - Noninvocable Member 'system.environment.specialfolder' cannot be used like a method. Error #2 - Then beside it i got "The name 'specialfolder' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Should be Environment.GetFolderPath